# Can I use the static keyword to only allocate new memory once?

Tags: c++, static, keyword

Say I have a function that is run multiple times. The function includes the code below:

```
static int *hello = new int;
```

Will `hello` only be allocated the first time it is run?

Comment: I would imagine so, yes. Why would it differ from non-pointers?

Comment: Thanks @chris - evidence of braindead moment deleted...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will be allocated only once.

But let me suggest you something else.
I suppose you have a function like that:

```
int* get_static_hello() {
    static int* value = new int;
    return value;
}
```

Well, you could very well do the following (it is one hundred percent correct):

```
int* get_static_hello() {
    static int value;
    return &value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually need to dynamically allocate an array, so it needs to use new. Thanks!

Comment: @user2045245, May I suggest `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will only be allocated once.

Things to be aware of when using a static variable in a function:

1. All instances of the class the function is in share this variable, it will be the same for all of them, and if it changes in one it changes for all.
2. If you thread this class the accessing of the static variable will not be threadsafe.

Answer (score -1):

Well, technically the int is allocated when the program starts. It will not be changed when the function is invoked. Apart from the fact the variable is only visible inside the function, it is exactly the same as declaring a static at the file level.

Comment: Uhhh. I'm pretty sure `new int` doesn't get executed and `value` doesn't get assigned until the function is run... That's why people often use statics in functions to avoid regular static initialization order problems.

Comment: @Clyde Dave is right. The `int` is not allocated when the program starts, but when the function is called for the first time.

Comment: The pointer to the int exists in the DataSegment when the program loads.  So it is 'allocated'.   But what it points to is allocated at run time.